Why does a C++ iterator reference need to be const?
I'm trying out this demo code to play with std::ranges::views::cartesian_product in g++13. I'm wondering about the for loop in main:
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

typedef  std::tuple<int const&, int const&, int const&> int_triple;

void print(int_triple x){
    std::cout << std::get<0>(x) << " " <<std::get<1>(x) << " "<<std::get<2>(x) << " " << std::endl;
}

int main(void){
    std::array<int, 2> x = {1,2};
    std::array<int, 2> y = {3,4};
    std::array<int, 2> z = {5, 6};

    for(const int_triple& t: std::views::cartesian_product(x,y,z)){
        print(t);
    }

    return 0;
}

Why is this OK:
for(const int_triple& t: std::views::cartesian_product(x,y,z))

but this throws the following error:
for(int_triple& t: std::views::cartesian_product(x,y,z))

cartprod_demo.cpp:16:59: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int_triple&’ {aka ‘std::tuple<const int&, const int&, const int&>&’} to an rvalue of type ‘int_triple’ {aka ‘std::tuple<const int&, const int&, const int&>’}
   16 |     for(int_triple& t: std::views::cartesian_product(x,y,z)){
      |                                                           ^
In file included from cartprod_demo.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/13/tuple:930:9: note:   after user-defined conversion: ‘constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&&) [with _UElements = {int&, int&, int&}; bool _Valid = true; typename std::enable_if<_TCC<_Valid>::__is_implicitly_constructible<_UElements ...>(), bool>::type <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {const int&, const int&, const int&}]’

How do I read this error?
I'm new to C++, so I want to understand this terse syntax. I get that the lvalue is just the variable t on the left-hand side, but that's pretty much all I can get from this.

"I'd like to ask if there are any suggested reading resources to understand these kind of semantics." - have a look at the definitive C++ book guide and list

In C++ it is not allowed to bind a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue (a temporary here). The error message is quite explicit about it.

One of the multiple duplicates: Why does this code give the error "cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘char*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘char*’".

Can you tell me what should happen if you do in a loop: t = int_triple{1, 2, 3}? When you attempt to answer this question need of const should be obvious.

Fyi you should never ever name the type of your for loop iterator, always use const auto& or auto& or auto&& , you could accidentally trigger type conversions when you name a type.

Your question is based on a wrong assumption. You thought std::range_reference_t is const int_triple& and ask why it is the case. Actually the type is something similar to int_triple, a non-reference type. std::range_reference_t not being a real reference may seem strange at first, but it's actually quite common for views.

In this case I would use structured binding: https://godbolt.org/z/Eoe81v8We

Re: "Why does a C++ iterator reference need to be const?" - t is not an iterator reference. It's a reference to whatever the dereferenced iterator returns.

cartesian_product() returns a view, and then the for loop uses that view's iterators to access the view's elements. The for loop dereferences those iterators to access the individual elements of the view and assign them to your t variable.
Your code:
for(const int_triple& t: std::views::cartesian_product(x,y,z)){
    print(t);
}

Is effectively equivalent to this:
{
    auto&& range = std::views::cartesian_product(x,y,z);
    auto begin = range.begin();
    auto end = range.end();
    for ( ; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        const int_triple& t = *begin; // <-- problem here
        print(t);
    }
}

In this situation, the iterator dereference is returning each tuple element by value, thus they are rvalues.
A const reference can bind to an rvalue, which is why const int_triple& t works, but a non-const reference cannot, which is why int_triple& t fails.  And that is exactly what the error message is complaining about:

cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int_triple&’ ... to an rvalue of type ‘int_triple’ ...


Interesting! For the range definition, does it have to be auto&& (a forwarding reference?) is that because the view is an rvalue?

Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for
